# How can mem_fun_ref be used without function templates?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use mem_fun_ref to send a reference to a member function of an object to another function, but I get `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.`

I didn't reflect this in the example, but I need to send the mem_fun_ref_t to a virtual function, which is why I didn't just make Flip a function template that takes a simple function object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Coin
{
public:
    Coin() {}
    std::string Flip ()
    {
        srand(23);
        int side = rand() % 2 + 1;

        std::string result = "";
        if (side == 1)
            result = "heads.";
        else
            result = "tails.";
        return result;
    }
};



std::string Flip(std::mem_fun_ref_t<std::string, Coin> flip)
{
    return flip();
}



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Flipping a coin..." << std::endl;
    std::string output = Flip(std::mem_fun_ref<std::string, Coin>(&Coin::Flip));
    std::cout << "The coin came up " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Member functions must be called with a `this` pointer bound in (object to act upon).

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense conceptually: A pointer-to-member(-function) is only useful in conjunction with an *object* reference. But you don't have an object!

Comment: And specifically, `mem_fun_ref_t<std::string, Coin>` is a functor whose `operator()` takes a `Coin&` and returns `string`.

Comment: Does `Coin::Flip` need to be a non-static member function? If `Coin::Flip` could be a static member function, it would simplify things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on [static member functions](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/), as well as [member function pointers](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html). There are three ways you can fix your problem.

First is to make `Coin::Flip` a static member function:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::string (*Flipper)(); // Function pointer typedef

class Coin
{
public:
    Coin() {}

    // Static member function. A pointer to a static member function can be
    // held in a regular function pointer.
    static std::string Flip ()
    {
        srand(23);
        int side = rand() % 2 + 1;
        return (side == 1) ? "heads." : "tails.";
    }
};

std::string Flip(Flipper flipper)
{
    return flipper();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Flipping a coin..." << std::endl;
    std::string output = Flip(&Coin::Flip);
    std::cout << "The coin came up " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

If `Coin::Flip` needs to be a non-static member function, you can pass a `Coin` instance to `Flip`, along with the member function pointer:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Coin
{
public:
    Coin() {}

    // Non-static member function.
    std::string Flip ()
    {
        srand(23);
        int side = rand() % 2 + 1;
        return (side == 1) ? "heads." : "tails.";
    }
};

typedef std::mem_fun_ref_t<std::string, Coin> Flipper;

// We need the Coin instance as well as the member function pointer.
std::string Flip(Coin& coin, Flipper flipper)
{
    // Invoke the flipper member function on the coin instance
    return flipper(coin);
}

int main()
{
    // Since we're using a non-static member function, we need an instance
    // of Coin.
    Coin coin;
    std::cout << "Flipping a coin..." << std::endl;
    std::string output = Flip(coin, mem_fun_ref(&Coin::Flip));
    std::cout << "The coin came up " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Finally, if the `Flipper` functor can be a member function from any kind of object (not only Coin), and you don't want the `Flip` free function to be a template, you'll need [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) that are part of the recent C++11 standard. `std::function` is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper that works with any kind of callable target: free functions, member functions, function objects, etc. If you can't use C++11, the Boost library has the equivalents [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html) and [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html).

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Coin
{
public:
    Coin() {}

    // Non-static member function.
    std::string Flip ()
    {
        srand(23);
        int side = rand() % 2 + 1;
        return (side == 1) ? "heads." : "tails.";
    }

    // Static member function.
    static std::string StaticFlip()
    {
        srand(23);
        int side = rand() % 2 + 1;
        return (side == 1) ? "heads." : "tails.";
    }
};

// Flipper is a generic function object wrapper that works with free functions,
// function objects, static member functions, and non-static member functions.
typedef std::function<std::string ()> Flipper;

std::string Flip(Flipper flipper)
{
    return flipper();
}

int main()
{
    // Example with non-static member function
    Coin coin;

    // Bind a Coin instance along with a Coin::Flip member function pointer.
    Flipper flipper1 = std::bind(&Coin::Flip, &coin);

    std::cout << "Flipping a coin..." << std::endl;
    std::string output = Flip(flipper1);
    std::cout << "The coin came up " << output << std::endl;

    // Example with static member function
    Flipper flipper2 = &Coin::StaticFlip;
    std::cout << "Flipping a coin..." << std::endl;
    output = Flip(flipper2);
    std::cout << "The coin came up " << output << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The third option would be perfect, except I'm unable to use C++11 or the Boost library in this case.

Comment: It turns out that the second option will probably work fine, as I would essentially be passing children of Coin into the Flip function anyway.